# How to place a div under a textarea and be able to handle events on it?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom-events

I want to make something like Grammarly, exactly like this:
[image]

The text is in a textarea, and a div for highlighting is under it, when I click on the red line, the correction card appears, but with z-index of the div less than the textarea's one, I am losing the events on it !

How can I implement such thing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If **Element A** has a lower `z-index` than (ie. is underneath) **Element B** *but* **Element B** has the following applied (either in the initial stylesheet or later, dynamically):

```
element-b {
pointer-events: none;
}
```

then any user clicking on **Element B** will *actually* be clicking on **Element A**.

Essentially the click goes straight through the element which cannot take *pointer-events* and instead hits the element beneath.

---

## Further Reading:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events

Comment: Thanks for you answer, but in this way I won't be able to listen to element B click event to show the corrections list :\
I'd appreciate is if you check grammarly chrome extension, I want to make the same functionality.

Comment: Yes, this is why I suggested adding the style _dynamically_. When the page first downloads **Element B** will  take pointer events, but while it is showing the corrections list, it will not.

Comment: @Rounin-StandingwithUkraine how do you then reset the pointer-events? I'm using hover, but "pointer-events: none;" triggers on mouse out.

Comment: The default value for pointer-events is: `pointer-events: auto` - see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events